# VS Code Breakpoints Skipping

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, breakpoints, vscode-debugger

I am using VS Code with python 3.9.3 and currently when I run debug on a basic python file the debugger skips over the breakpoints. My python install is using a venv called 'DAQ' in the same directory as the python file. Does anyone know why this is happening, and how I can fix it?

Below is my launch.json and cmd call from vscode

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "justMyCode": false
    }
]
}

C:\Users\danie\Documents\CyRoc\DAQ\Honeywell> c: && cd c:\Users\danie\Documents\CyRoc\DAQ\Honeywell && cmd /C "c:\Users\danie\Documents\CyRoc\DAQ\Honeywell\Post-Process\DAQ\Scripts\python.exe c:\Users\danie\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.2.1924087327\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher 59012 -- c:\Users\danie\Documents\CyRoc\DAQ\Honeywell\Post-Process\read_file.py "
```

Comment: without your python it is hard to tell, sometimes the compiled python code has no code for a particular line so a breakpoint on that line will never get hit.

Comment: Does it stop at the first line of the python script? Does it skip all the breakpoints or just some of them? Does the skipped breakpoint have an expression or hitc ount?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT it never stops. It skips all breakpoints. I even wrote very basic HelloWorld level scripts to no avail.

Comment: @Bob Could you execute the python script successfully? And your virtual environment is weird, Usually the virtual environment was under the workspace folder(Honeywell) instead of the subfolder(Post-Process). Could you switch the python interpreter to a global environment?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Yeah the script executed successfully. Do you want me to move my venv or use my base python install?